# Azure user GRANTs for SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I've been struggling my way through create a new DB user for an Azure SQL database. Here are the three statements I'm doing:

1. Create a new Azure login:

   ```
   CREATE LOGIN [bobby] WITH PASSWORD = 'Password1'
   ```
2. Create a new DB user within the Azure login:

   ```
   CREATE USER bobby FOR LOGIN bobby;
   ALTER USER bobby with DEFAULT_SCHEMA = 'newschema';
   ```
3. To add a user to a DB group for that database — note, it is only for that database (whatever is in the current `USE` command):

   ```
   EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'bobby'
   ```

For the life of me I couldn't figure out how to do `GRANT`s for step three. Every time I would try a statement it would give me some flavor of "permission denied" even though I am the one (and only) admin user in Azure. Is this the only way to add roles in Azure? Or am I totally missing something here?

Comment: Are you using Server admin account to run this statements?

Comment: @LeonYue yes. Is there an easier way?'

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: `ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [bobby];`

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 yes, please try the command gofr1 provided. `EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'bobby'` is usually used in ADW.

Comment: Hi @samuelbrody1249, is the issue solved now?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure SQL database, the whole step should be this:

**1. Run the command in master DB:**

```
    CREATE LOGIN [bobby] WITH PASSWORD = 'Password1'
```

**2. Go to the user database, run the command bellow:**

```
    CREATE USER bobby FOR LOGIN bobby;
    ALTER USER bobby with DEFAULT_SCHEMA = 'newschema';
    ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [bobby];
```

Please use server admin to create the login or user firstly.

Ref document here: [ALTER ROLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)